# Can I access to localhost from AWS WorkSpace

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

I use the aws workspace windows standard edition.
I want to access localhost:8080 from aws workspace windows.
How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try? What happened? Were you running anything on that port?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as your windows firewall rules allows it I don't see any reason why it should not work.